# Looking for a good overview of atonement theory (book or other resource)

Tags: atonement, resource-request

I am looking for a good overview/introduction to atonement theory that covers multiple points of view so that I can better understand the difference between the various different theories.  I am not looking for someone to outline them here, as I would like a more thorough answer than what would be reasonable in a SE answer.  I am also looking for something beyond what Wikipedia provides, as frankly it is not very helpful.

Perhaps a book that devotes a chapter or two to an academic presentation of several different views, but doesn't (strongly) argue for or against any of them, would be best.

Comment: Shorter than what you are looking for, but much more coherent and succinct than Wikipedia, is [Leon Morris on the Theories of the Atonement](http://www.monergism.com/thethreshold/articles/onsite/atonementmorris2.html).

Comment: Should this be closed because it is a list question? At any rate, I recommend The Cross of Christ by Stott. He covers several atonement theories, though maybe not as extensively as you would like.

Comment: @Steve I didn't ask for all such resources, nor would I want such a list. :)  ... Recommend an X questions are considered on-topic at most SEs, although I'm not sure if we've had a meta discussion on it here or not.

Comment: [The Nature of the Atonement: Four Views](http://www.amazon.com/The-Nature-Atonement-Four-Views/dp/0830825703) is probably good, but I haven't read it.

Answer (score 0):

What first comes to mind is Gustaf Aulen's *Christus Victor*, followed by Jürgen Moltmann's *The Crucified God* -- I have both on my shelf and they're well-worn.

Though if you don't want a full-length book, here's a great [brief summarization](https://www.sdmorrison.org/7-theories-of-the-atonement-summarized/).  It also has a bibliography (which includes both my recommendations).

Comment: Book titles should be underlined, not italicized.  I can't figure out how to do that, though.